# What means the local _ in C#?

Tags: c#

First of it all: my C# Knowledge is depricated because i do other projects in the meantime.
So i come back and see whats up now, but there is one thing i do not understand.

This is now valid in C#

```
_ = new object();
```

I try to use a search engine of my choice but u can imagine search for "C# _" isnt very helpful to search for. Can someone explain whats going on here? My idea was this is placeholder to pop the result back on the stack and avoid agressive compiler optimization. But at the end, i have no idea.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards

Comment: Discards just mean: "create an object and throw it away". Usual use-case is for `out`-params you won´t use in your client-code. That´s why your example is pretty pointless.

Comment: fun fact i copy code from msdn and intelli sense show me that way.

Comment: in other words, i'm right. so whats the advantage?

Comment: okay i see from duplicate hints, its  a rare out argument case.
make sense!